# How many speeches should the electorate expect within a session and within a legislation period, respectively?

Tags: probability, expected-value, means

### Details:

Each time parliament convenes there is enough time for 12 speakers on each day on average.

Legislation period lasts for 5 years

Each year there are 4 seassion of 3 calender months and in each session there are exactly 60 days in which parliament convenes.

### The Question:

> How many speeches should the electorate expect within a session and within a legislation period, respectively?

### My Attempt:

$4\times 60=240$

$240\times 12=2880$ for 1 year

Should I multiply by 5 for the legislation period?

Please help me

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put units on your numbers, like showing that $240$ is the number of days per year that the parliament meets.  You have missed computing the number of speeches per session.  Then for the number of speeches per legislation period you should multiply by $5$ for the number of years.  If you note the $2880$ is speeches/year and that you want speeches/legislative period it is clear.